# The word/term for a series of bad/negative events turning to a positive outcome

Tags: single-word-requests

I tried on google every word and phrase I could come up but I just couldn't find it. I'm pretty sure I've seen this word before and it's english.

Comment: Happy accident? Eucatastrophe?

Comment: Reversal of fortune?

Comment: Every cloud has a silver lining? It's an ill wind [that blows no one any good]?

Answer (score 5):

I think that ***[a blessing in disguise](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coast)*** may fit your description :

​

> something that seems bad or unlucky at first, but results in something good happening later:*Losing that job was a blessing in disguise really.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: The correctness of this answer hinges on how much OP's expected definition relies on the **series** of negative events. Your answer is correct, but implicitly limits itself to a **single** negative event ending up as a positive one.

Comment: And without the constraint of a series of bad events, this question should be closed as a duplicate rather than answered. 'A blessing in disguise' has been given in an answer before.

Answer (score 1):

**salutary**

From [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/salutary):

> **salutary** ... (especially with reference to something unwelcome or unpleasant) producing good effects; beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

J.R.R. Tolkien coined the word **eucatastrophe**, and I think it would match the word you’re looking for.

From [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/eucatastrophe):

> **eucatastrophe** A sudden and favourable resolution of events in a story; a happy ending.